# How to use strtok() tokens

Tags: c, strtok

As per this [description](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm), `strtok()` delimitate a string into tokens by the delimiter given, returns a pointer to the first token found in the string. All subsequent tokens need to be traversed via a loop, like the example code given in the link.

Does each token auto terminate with `NULL`? i.e. can I simply assign each token to a variable and use it or does it need `strncpy()` to be copied to an allocated space?

For example, would this be valid?

```
   char str[80] = "This is - www.tutorialspoint.com - website";
   const char s[2] = "-";
   char *token;

   char *test[4];
   int test_count = 0;
   memset(test, 0x00, 4);

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) {
      test[test_count] = token;
      test_count++;
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }
```

Comment: This is what it does. Replacing the delimiters with `\0`s.

Comment: To clearify, you can't assign tokens to variables, but you can assign tokens addresses to pointers and use the pointers

Comment: It is a matter of taste, of course. But as far as I have observed, most high-rep StackOverflow users prefer this as a reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok

Comment: The delimiters are replaced with NUL characters as described in any reasonable standard library documentation.  What is it you still don't understand having  read the documentation - that would make a better question perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok()` works on your original input string, by **replacing** the first occurence of a character in the list of delimeters with a `'\0'`. So yes, this is the intended usage as you describe it.

Side notes:

- don't write things like

  ```
  const char s[2] = "-";
  ```

  just using

  ```
  const char s[] = "-";
  ```

  lets the compiler determine the correct size automatically
- in this special case, just passing `"-"` to `strtok()` (or a `#define` to `"-"`) would do fine, a decent compiler recognizes identical string literals and creates only one instance of them.
- just in case it's helpful to see some code, here's [a simple strtok implementation](https://github.com/Zirias/clang-libdos/blob/master/src/string/string_strtok.c#L13) I did myself a while back.

Comment: The side-notes, while helpful, strictly belong in the question's comments section.

Comment: @Clifford you're the first one I come across expressing this view. It's quite common here to provide additional improvement suggestions on OP's code in an answer. Is there any meta discussion about that?

Comment: I personally think it clutters the answer and is unnecessary.  Since the issues are not relevant or essential to the question, the question may be modified to "clean-up" the code and then these comments will stand orphaned and incongruous.  If posted in a comment the author is free to apply those improvements to the question so as not to distract focus from his question (or someone else could edit it).  You can add comments to your own answer too, which might be appropriate for the last bullet-point.  I am however ambivalent - it was just an observation/opinion - feel free to disregard.